# Is there any Event for extension selection in the main menu de Sony Smartwatch 2?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I need to send a new notification when the user presses the icon for the notification extension in the watch. This is possible?

I reviewed  the Sony API but I not found any that help me in this problem.

Comment: Is the "notification extension" you refer to, an extension that you have developed yourself?

Comment: @shellströmSONY Oh, yes... o maybe can be a control extension :)
I need the event that recognizes the user "click"  for develope a notificacion send n_n

Comment: Do you need to
1: catch the event when someone taps (starts) the extension icon in the SmartWatch 2 launcher or,
2: catch an event when someone taps a notification (performs an action) that has appeared on the watch?

Comment: 1: catch the event when someone taps (starts) the extension icon in the SmartWatch 2 launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SmartExtension APIs support catching of launch events when you implement extensions that use the Control API.

To catch these events you can override the SmartExtensionUtils methods

- onStart()
- onResume()

See, http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/control/ControlExtension

As an example the AdvancedLayouts sample included in Sony Add-on SDK 3.0 shows how onStart() and onResume() can be used.

Note that

- this only works for the Control API extensions
- the caught launch events only work for your own implemented extensions. It will not be able to catch the launch event of all installed extensions.

Comment: I had planned to use it in the notification extension too.
But thanks for giving me light in the way :D